# Install monit in Debian 10 (buster)

Tags: debian, monit

I try to install `monit` in Debian Buster, but it sais

```
Package monit is not available, but is referred to by another package.
```

How do I find out this referenced package? Or do I need to install an alternative monitoring too in buster?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On Debian Buster, `monit` is available on backports repository.

Add buster-backports:

```
printf "%s\n" "deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster-backports main" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-backports.list
```

Install `monit`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -t buster-backports monit
```